# What are dimensions in multi dimensional array in practical sense

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am a starter in the field of ML and wants to understand "Multi Dimensional Array". My current understanding is as follows. Please help me where i am wrong.

Suppose I have data of customers, we can refer customers as *items*.

Now suppose each *item i.e. each individual has a Customer identification no (CIN)* - we can call this as a one dimensional matrix.

extending the same example,

now each item has list of attributes e.g. CIN, Gender, Height, weight, Eye colour. If i want to arrange them it will be a 2 dimensional matrix. Row representing students, columns representing their physical attributes "Roll No, Gender, Height, weight, Eye colour".

Now suppose i add another list of different attributes - Past purchase history i.e. Last purchase date and invoice no.

Can we call a matrix which has both phyical attributes "Roll No, Gender, Height, weight, Eye colour" and "Last purchase date and invoice no." is this a 3 dimensional matrix ?

Is it the grouping into physical and purchase history which will make it a 3 d matrix.

I can still store it as a 2 d matrix (like a spread sheet) with physical and purchase history as columns or like 2 sheets with common link as CIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting confused between dimensions of an array and dimensions for a ML model also called features or independent variables.

When you train a model each piece of information that you pass to the model is a feature or a dimension. So for example Roll No, Gender, Height are all features. If you add Last purchase date and invoice those are also features. If you add all of them in a dataframe, each row of the dataframe can be thought of as an 1-D array.

The grouping of physical attributes and purchase history which will not make it a 3-D matrix.

3-D arrays or n-D arrays are called tensors. They are something completely different.

Comment: Okay. Thanks
Can you help with a simple example of simplest tensor?

Comment: Tensors can be represented in Python using the numpy N-dimensional array (ndarray). You can read more about them here --https://machinelearningmastery.com/introduction-to-tensors-for-machine-learning/#:~:text=Tensors%20in%20Python,as%20a%20list%20of%20lists.

Comment: I found a very useful video on understanding basic of tensor. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaQeXi4E7gA